# Combining the bootstrap collapse tool with a form checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working on a settings page for my website. I want to combine checkboxes with Bootstrap's collapse tool.

currently I have this code going for me:

```
<label class="switch"> <input type="checkbox" name="wallenabled" value="1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample" checked>
    <div class="slider round"></div>
</label><br>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <p>Who can view your wall?</p>
        <select name=viewwall class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Everyone</option>
            <option value="1">Friends</option>
            <option value="2">Nobody</option>
        </select><br>
            <p>Who can write on your wall?</p>
        <select name=writewall class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Everyone</option>
            <option value="1">Friends</option>
            <option value="2">Nobody</option>
        </select><br>
    </div><br>
```

At the moment it collapses once I press the checkbox. But is it possible for it to collapse only if the checkbox is checked?

Kind regards,

PS: I've got complaints in my earlier questions, I would love to hear some tips so my questions get better/more clear ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It isnt the Bootstrap one. But it still looks really nice ^^

Code:

```
<h3>Wall</h3><br>

    <label class="switch"> <input id="openWall" type="checkbox" name="wallenabled" value="1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" <?php if($priv['wallenabled'] == 1) { ?> checked <?php } ?> onclick="openWall();" >
        <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label><br>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            openWall();
        });
        function openWall() {
            var checkbox = document.getElementById("openWall");
            var state = checkbox.checked;
            if(state)
                $("#collapseWall").show(400);
            else
                $("#collapseWall").hide(400);
            }
    </script>

            <div class="collapse" id="collapseWall">
                <p>Who can view your wall?</p>
                <select name=viewwall class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">Everyone</option>
                    <option value="1">Friends</option>
                    <option value="2">Nobody</option>
                </select><br>
                <p>Who can write on your wall?</p>
                <select name=writewall class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">Everyone</option>
                    <option value="1">Friends</option>
                    <option value="2">Nobody</option>
                </select><br>
            </div><br>
```